# Efficiently convert numpy matrix to Vaex DataFrame

Tags: arrays, pandas, numpy, python-3.10, vaex

I'm trying to turn my wide (100K+ columns) 2D numpy data into a Vaex Dataframe. I'm reading through the documentation, and I see two relevant functions:

[from_items](https://vaex.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#vaex.from_items)

[from_arrays](https://vaex.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#vaex.from_arrays)

but both give me an entire column `x`, where each row is a numpy array. What I expected was for Vaex to intelligently recognize that I want each column of data from the numpy array to be its own separate column in the Vaex DataFrame.

`vaex.from_arrays(x=2d_numpy_matrix)` gives me:

```
x
---
0 np.array(1,2,3)
1 np.array(4,5,6)
```

when I wanted:

```
0 | 1 | 2 (Column header)
---
1 | 2 | 3
4 | 5 | 6
```

My workaround is `vaex.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame(2d_numpy_matrix))` but this is embarrassingly slow. Is there a more CPU-time efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unpack a dictionary comprehension like this:

```
import numpy as np
import vaex

headers = np.array(['1','2','3'])
data = np.array([[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]])

df = vaex.from_arrays(**{header: column for header, column in zip(headers, data)})
```

This yields:

```
>>> df
#    0    1    2
0    1    2    3
1    4    5    6
```

Comment: What's the time-efficiency of this versus `from_pandas` for huge data?

Comment: I ran a test on a 4 mil row, 50+ column dataset. from_pandas takes ~0.15 seconds to create the vaex dataframe while the method above takes ~0.05 seconds.